# Problem with intent putExtra() passed item when querying Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am having some issues with the intent object. I already retrieved it with the new Activity but it doesn't work when passed to Firestore queries. The passed extra is the sellerId but surprisingly, if I use the auth Id of the current used using below code it works.

Though working, I actually don't need the my own auth id but the seller instead. There seems to be an issues with querying for me using extras as it is not recognized on both onCreate or onStart while doing a Firestore query.

Kindly enlighten me please and thanks in advance for anyone who can help solve this issue below.

All variables/dependencies below declared already here

```
     // This works
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            id= user.getCurrentId();

            
         firestore.collection("Users").document(id)
                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable 
            FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", error);
                                return;
                            }

                            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
 
                                String name = snapshot.getString("name");
                                String id = snapshot.getString("id");
                                String email = snapshot.getString("email");
                                String description = snapshot.getString("description");

                            }
                        }
                    });


         // This doesn't work wether onCreate() or onStart()
         sellerDetail = getIntent().getStringExtra("seller");
         firestore.collection("Users").document(id)
                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable 
            FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", error);
                                return;
                            }

                            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
 
                                String name = snapshot.getString("name");
                                String id = snapshot.getString("id");
                                String email = snapshot.getString("email");
                                String description = snapshot.getString("description");

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry bro just some errors on my part. Its ok now.